# Form input ng-value seems filled but is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-value

I am building an AngularJS app. I have a problem with a form that is filled with ng-value.

The input field is filled in, the user can see text but when the user presses the 'change' button it becomes undefined. Any thoughts?

My controller code:

```
// Fictional data it wineById will be a JSON object.
$scope.wineById = {"id":"4","name":"fdfvs1","percentage":"vcxz1"}

$scope.edit = function () {
    var wine = {
        id:$scope.wineById.id,
        name:$scope.name,
        percentage:$scope.percentage
    };

    console.log($scope.name, $scope.percentage);
};
```

HTML:

```
<form novalidate ng-submit="edit()">
        <label>ID wine: <input type="text" ng-value="wineById.id" ng-model="id" ng-disabled="true"></label> <br>
        <label>Name wine: <input type="text" ng-value="wineById.name" ng-model="name"></label> <br>
        <label>Percentage wine: <input type="text" ng-value="wineById.percentage" ng-model="percentage"></label> <br>

        <input type="submit" value="Change">
</form>
```

Case 1:

Got existing input in my fields. Pressing the button without changing the input data in the fields. Everything becomes undefined.

Case 2 (the one that works):

Got existing input in my fields. Changing all the fields with different data and pressing the button. Everything is changed.

How can I fix case 1?

Comment: Why you are using ng-value. ng-model is enough to bind the value.

Comment: I use ng-value to fill up the input fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html as following if you still want to use `ng-value` for whatever reason:

```
<form novalidate ng-submit="edit()">
  <label>ID wine:
   <input type="text" ng-init="id=wineById.id" ng-model="id" ng-value="wineById.id" ng-disabled="true">
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>Name wine:
    <input ng-init="name=wineById.name" type="text" ng-value="wineById.name" ng-model="name">
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>Percentage wine:
    <input ng-init="percentage=wineById.percentage" type="text" ng-value="wineById.percentage" ng-model="percentage">
  </label>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Change">
</form>
```

Better approach would be to use just `ng-model` (unless you don't want two way binding)

```
<form novalidate ng-submit="edit()">
    <label>ID wine:
      <input type="text" ng-model="wineById.id" ng-disabled="true">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>Name wine:
      <input type="text" ng-model="wineById.name">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>Percentage wine:
      <input type="text" ng-model="wineById.percentage">
    </label>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Change">
</form>
```

[**Live Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/02qL85?p=preview)

Comment: I get existing data filled in the input fields with ng-value. I use ng-model to bind. But the existing data that is filled in the input fields is there, but if I press 'change' the input fields are empty.

Comment: did you check the live demo?

Comment: This is what I want, but how did you fill the input fields? It remains empty at my side.

Comment: From the information you have provided in your question, there's nothing much to guess IMO. I would recommend checking if any other sections of the code is changing your values.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using ng-value, angular supports two way binding, ng-model is enough for binding data.

```
<form novalidate ng-submit="edit()">
    <label>ID wine: <input type="text" ng-model="id" ng-disabled="true"></label> <br>
    <label>Name wine: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></label> <br>
    <label>Percentage wine: <input type="text" ng-model="percentage"></label> <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Change">
</form>
```

Comment: I use ng-value to fill up the input fields. This still shows up as undefined

Comment: `console.log($scope.name, $scope.percentage);` if its working in your code, than `scope` bind the value using ng-model only.

Comment: It works if I change the data in the input fields. When I leave the data as it is filled in it says 'undefined'

Comment: Take the advantage of angular two way binding. No ng-value or ng-init required.

Comment: Than, there is controller issue, are you using more than one controller?